# How to divide/multiply value of a column with value of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks liks this

```
Minutes Played, Points, Assists

      MP   PTS   TRB   AST    FG%  BLK    3P%
0   2810   793   678   117  0.485   74  0.315
1    263   101    30    19  0.402    7  0.385
2   4241  1170  1178   144  0.548  201  0.000
```

I want to convert that data frame to data-frame with these columns

```
Points/Minutes, Assists/Minutes
```

Basically first column is total-minutes played, I want to covert all of the remaining stats to per minute basis.

Right I am doing

```
 input_data['PTS']/input_data['MP']
```

and then I am concatenating all of the series, what is the pythonic way of doing this? How can I do this using Map/lambda operation?

Comment: Hello @Dude, could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with example input, to help us help you, and understand what exactly you're stuck on?

Comment: You have inconsistent column naming in your post. It's best to have a concrete SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: @zmo updated the question with the actual data-frame.

Comment: and can you provide the simplest/canonical snippet of code that initialises an example dataframe, and how you use it, and where/how you're being stuck? Also do you want to _concatenate_ `points/minutes` or create a new value with the actual result of calculating `points/minutes`? i.e. do you want to store `793/2810` as a string or do you want to calculate and store `0.28…`?

Comment: @zmo Updated the question again to clarify further, I want a new data frame with per-minute stats , and I want to store it in the same data-type as earlier i.e. float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
print input_data
     MP   PTS   TRB  AST    FG%  BLK    3P%
0  2810   793   678  117  0.485   74  0.315
1   263   101    30   19  0.402    7  0.385
2  4241  1170  1178  144  0.548  201  0.000

input_data['A'] = input_data['PTS']/input_data['MP']
input_data['B'] = input_data['AST']/input_data['MP']
print input_data
     MP   PTS   TRB  AST    FG%  BLK    3P%         A         B
0  2810   793   678  117  0.485   74  0.315  0.282206  0.041637
1   263   101    30   19  0.402    7  0.385  0.384030  0.072243
2  4241  1170  1178  144  0.548  201  0.000  0.275878  0.033954

print pd.DataFrame({'A': input_data['A'],'B': input_data['B']}, index=input_data.index)
          A         B
0  0.282206  0.041637
1  0.384030  0.072243
2  0.275878  0.033954
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the role of index=input_data.index here?

Comment: It means you re-use `index` of original `dataframe` in new `dataframe`

Answer (score 1):

Divide all columns in the dataframe except the first by the first column.

```
df.iloc[:, ].apply(lambda s: s / df.iloc[:, 0])
        PTS       TRB       AST       FG%       BLK       3P%
0  0.282206  0.241281  0.041637  0.000173  0.026335  0.000112
1  0.384030  0.114068  0.072243  0.001529  0.026616  0.001464
2  0.275878  0.277765  0.033954  0.000129  0.047394  0.000000
```

This also works:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].div(df.iloc[:, 0].values, axis=0)
```

I believe you will then need to recalculate your FG% and 3P% columns.  This will do the division on your original dataframe, leaving MP, FG% and 3P% untouched.

```
df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 5]] = df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 5]].div(df.iloc[:, 0].values, axis=0)

>>> df
     MP       PTS       TRB       AST    FG%       BLK    3P%
0  2810  0.282206  0.241281  0.041637  0.485  0.026335  0.315
1   263  0.384030  0.114068  0.072243  0.402  0.026616  0.385
2  4241  0.275878  0.277765  0.033954  0.548  0.047394  0.000
```

p.s.  Go Warriors!!!

Comment: Yeah, I am not supposed to normalized those two columns. I can handle them through the index. Could you please explain `lambda s: s / df.iloc[:, 0]` part?

Comment: It performs the lambda function on each column (series) of the dataframe.  So `s` is the series column, and `df.iloc[:, 0]` is the first column.  `iloc` is integer indexing. `[:, 0]` means to take all of the rows from the first column (using zero based indexing).

Answer (score 0):

No, concatenating the new series is plenty idiomatic.

You can also use `df['newcol'] = ...` to build up what you want.

Comment: Can you tell me what would be the map/lamdba command to achieve this?